# ggplot error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Option_type' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe

```
Cars = data.frame(Category = c(1,2,3,3,2,3,3,4), Brand= c(3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2), 
Sales = c(847,143,554,30,44,140,445,847)
```

I am trying to use ggplot to get Total Sales by Category (and Brand) with the below codes

```
Cars %>% 
  group_by(Category, Brand) %>% 
  summarise(Total_Sales = sum(Sales)) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=Category, y=Total_Sales)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Brand), stat = 'identity', position = "dodge")
```

But i get the following `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Brand' not found`

When i tried to re-run the codes line by line to find the error source, i get another error when i left out the final line of code with the error source object "Brand". This time I get `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Category' not found` when i ran the below

```
Cars %>% 
  group_by(Category, Brand) %>% 
  summarise(Total_Sales = sum(Sales)) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=Category, y=Total_Sales)) #+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Brand), stat = 'identity', position = "dodge")
```

Been stuck at this for a while and couldnt solve it even after looking through similar problems posted, appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: I run your code and do not get an error (though you are missing a close-paren on the `Cars` definition); R-3.5.3, ggplot2-3.3.0, win10. (The second plot shows no data, but that's because you don't add `geom_bar` to the plot.)

Comment: My guess is that you've also loaded `plyr` (perhaps inadvertently) and [in the wrong order](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/347). Type in `summarise` (nothing else) and confirm that it says either `<environment: namespace:plyr>` (this is likely your problem) or `<environment: namespace:dplyr>` (in which case there is another problem going on).

Comment: For now, run your code using `dplyr::summarise` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. It was really the problem with having plyr loaded! Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: (Another option is to `detach` the plyr package, not sure if you're using it elsewhere or if it was loaded due to dependencies.)

Comment: Yes I'm using it somewhere. No wonder the ggplot codes originally worked, but mysteriously churned out the error a few days after. So it was due to me loading in plyr (and after dplyr in sequence) thereafter!

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, I was looking for that link.